# How can I create fake db using django-seed with code?

Tags: django

I need to create fake database. If I use command: python3 manage.py seed api --number=15 it works fine. But how can I create fake DB using with code?

There some example of code:

```
from django_seed import Seed

seeder = Seed.seeder()

from myapp.models import Game, Player
seeder.add_entity(Game, 5)
seeder.add_entity(Player, 10, {
    'score':    lambda x: random.randint(0, 1000),
    'nickname': lambda x: seeder.faker.email(),
})

inserted_pks = seeder.execute()
```

How can I run it?

Comment: what do you mean by saing `fake database`?

Comment: @oruchkin database with fictional information, just for testing app